# Macro that moves many sections of my worksheet is getting a syntax error, where did I go wrong?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, syntax-error

I somehow broke this super awesome code VBasic2008 gave me a few months ago. The workbook was getting super slow, probably because I wasn't using it properly and I just kept bolting things onto it. So I have just recreated it to see if I could simplify some of my additions and if I could remove any steps.
I have one macro that runs most of the others but as it ran and moved into the big section of the process that moves many different types of rows, I'm getting a syntax error that I didn't before. It gave me the error on the first section (NoAddress) so I'm expecting it to do the same on each of the following sections.

```
Sub MoveMatchingRows( _
        ByVal SourceWorksheet As Worksheet, _
        ByVal SourceColumn As Long, _
        ByVal SourceCriteria As Variant, _
        ByVal DestinationWorksheet As Worksheet, _
        Optional ByVal DestinationColumn As Long = 1, _
        Optional ByVal DoClearPreviousDestinationData As Boolean = False)
    
    Const ProcTitle As String = "Move Matching Rows"
    
    ' Remove any previous filters.
    If SourceWorksheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        SourceWorksheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    
    ' Filter.
    Dim srg As Range ' Source Range (Headers and Data)
    Set srg = SourceWorksheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    srg.AutoFilter SourceColumn, SourceCriteria, xlFilterValues
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Data Range (no headers).
    Dim sdrg As Range
    Set sdrg = srg.Resize(srg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    ' Clear Destination worksheet.
    If DoClearPreviousDestinationData Then ' new data, copies headers
        DestinationWorksheet.Cells.Clear
    End If
    
    ' Attempt to create a reference to the Source Data Filtered Rows Range.
    Dim sdfrrg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set sdfrrg = sdrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not sdfrrg Is Nothing Then
        
        ' Create a reference to the Destination Cell (also, add headers).
        Dim dCell As Range ' Destination Cell
        Set dCell = DestinationWorksheet.Cells(1, DestinationColumn)
        If IsEmpty(dCell) Then
            srg.Rows(1).Copy dCell
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1)
        Else
            Set dCell = DestinationWorksheet.Cells( _
                DestinationWorksheet.Rows.Count, DestinationColumn) _
                .End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        
        With sdfrrg
            .Copy dCell
            
            ' Either delete the entire worksheet rows...
            '.EntireColumn.Delete
            
            ' ... or remove filter to prevent...
            SourceWorksheet.AutoFilterMode = False
            ' ... deleting the entire worksheet rows leaving possible data
            ' to the right (after the empty column) intact.
            .Delete xlShiftUp
        
        End With
    
    Else ' no matches
        
        SourceWorksheet.AutoFilterMode = False
   
    End If
        
End Sub
_____________________________________________________________________

Sub NoAddress()
    MoveMatchingRows Sheet1, 6, "=", Sheet12, 1, False
End Sub
________________________________________________

Sub Zoos()
    MoveMatchingRows Sheet1, 4, "*Zoos*", Sheet11, 1, False
End Sub
______________________________________

Sub MoveMemorial()
    MoveMatchingRows Sheet1, 18, "Memorial", Sheet6, 1, False
End Sub
_______________________________________

Sub MoveHonor()
    MoveMatchingRows Sheet1, 18, "Honor", Sheet6, 1, False
End Sub
_______________________

Sub MoveMatchingGift()
    MoveMatchingRows Sheet1, 4, "*Matching Gift*", Sheet9, 1, False
End Sub
______________________

Sub MovePayroll()
    MoveMatchingRows Sheet1, 4, "*Payroll*", Sheet9, 1, False
End Sub
________________________________

Sub NotGenOpFund()
    MoveMatchingRows Sheet1, 23, "<>*FD.IND.GenOp*", Sheet12, 1, False
End Sub
_____________________________________________________________________

Sub GiftMemberships()
    MoveMatchingRows Sheet1, 15, "<>", Sheet10, 1, False
End Sub
_____________________________________________________________________

Sub More_Gift_Mems()
    MoveMatchingRows Sheet1, 25, "*gift for*", Sheet10, 1, False
End Sub
____________________________________________________________________

Sub Gift_Mem_Recipient()
    MoveMatchingRows Sheet1, 31, "<>", Sheet10, 1, False
End Sub
__________________________________

Sub Move_Managed()
    MoveMatchingRows Sheet1, 19, "<>", Sheet5, 1, False
End Sub
___________________________

Sub Stock_InKind_IRA()
    MoveMatchingRows Sheet1, 34, "<>", Sheet7, 1, False
End Sub
_____________________________________________________________________

Sub Move_DAF()
    MoveMatchingRows Sheet1, 42, "<>*/*", Sheet8, 1, False
End Sub
______________________

Sub Oddballs()
    MoveMatchingRows Sheet1, 3, "<> *AF.IND*", Sheet12, 1, False
End Sub
_____________________________


Sub Over_500_Unmanaged()
    MoveMatchingRows Sheet1, 15, ">=500", Sheet4, 1, False
End Sub
_____________________________

Sub Over_250_Unmanaged()
    MoveMatchingRows Sheet1, 15, ">=250", Sheet3, False
End Sub
```

What did I do wrong here?

Update (4.8.22)
I removed the "...1, FALSE" from everything but I am still getting an error that says the subroutine may not be available or all macros may be disabled. When you said to put quotes around all of my numbers, you weren't talking about the numbers that reference the data columns were you? I don't think you were but I tried it anyway and it didn't help. Do you have any suggestions on what I might try next?

Comment: Do you actually have `_____________________________`  between subroutines? Those should be commented out.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks. But now it's getting hung up a little farther down in the code.```    Set sdrg = srg.Resize(srg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)```

Comment: What does "hung up" mean specifically?

Comment: Run-time error '1004':
Application-Defined or object-defined error

Comment: Add `Debug.Print srg.Rows.Count` right before and run - what is the output in the Immediate Window?

Comment: Have you included `Option Explicit` as first row in your code? Are all variables e.g. `Sheet1` declared and assigned?

Comment: Cannot run the macro 'NoAddress'. The Macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

Comment: How are you calling `NoAddress` ?

Comment: Tagging in @VBasic2008

Answer (score 1):

### Move Filtered Rows to Another Worksheet

- Here's another improvement. Hopefully, it'll last longer than the first.
- It will fail when using numbers, so put them in quotes e.g. `"7"`.
- `xlFilterValues` is used to allow multiple criteria e.g. `Array("4", "7")` or `Array("Yes", "Maybe")`.
- All your examples use the parameters `1` and `False` for the last two arguments. You can safely omit them because they are the default values i.e. `MoveMatchingRows Sheet1, 6, "=", Sheet12` (the meaning of `Optional... = 1` and `Optional... = False`).
- In your last example, you have used `False` as the 5th argument instead of a reasonable positive integer so it will fail i.e. with this new code, it will just do almost nothing.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub MoveFilteredRows( _
        ByVal SourceWorksheet As Worksheet, _
        ByVal SourceColumn As Long, _
        ByVal SourceCriteria As Variant, _
        ByVal DestinationWorksheet As Worksheet, _
        Optional ByVal DestinationColumn As Long = 1, _
        Optional ByVal DoClearPreviousDestinationData As Boolean = False)
    Const ProcName As String = "MoveFilteredRows"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Show all rows if the source worksheet is filtered.
    If SourceWorksheet.FilterMode Then SourceWorksheet.ShowAllData
    
    ' Reference the source range (has headers).
    Dim srg As Range ' Source Range (one row of headers and data)
    Set srg = SourceWorksheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    ' Show all rows if the destination worksheet is filtered.
    If DestinationWorksheet.FilterMode Then DestinationWorksheet.ShowAllData
    
    ' Reference the destination first cell and take care of the headers.
    Dim dfCell As Range
    If DoClearPreviousDestinationData Then
        DestinationWorksheet.UsedRange.Clear
        Set dfCell = DestinationWorksheet.Cells(1, DestinationColumn)
        srg.Rows(1).Copy dfCell ' copy headers
        If srg.Rows.Count = 1 Then Exit Sub
        Set dfCell = dfCell.Offset(1)
    Else
        If srg.Rows.Count = 1 Then Exit Sub ' don't want to copy headers
        With DestinationWorksheet.Columns(DestinationColumn) _
                .Resize(, srg.Columns.Count)
            Set dfCell = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
            If dfCell Is Nothing Then
                Set dfCell = .Cells(1)
                srg.Rows(1).Copy dfCell ' copy headers anyway
                Set dfCell = dfCell.Offset(1)
            Else
                Set dfCell = .Cells(dfCell.Row + 1, 1)
            End If
        End With
    End If
    
    ' Filter.
    srg.AutoFilter SourceColumn, SourceCriteria, xlFilterValues
    
    ' (Attempt to) reference the source data filtered range.
    Dim sdfrg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set sdfrg = srg.Resize(srg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) _
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    SourceWorksheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    ' Move i.e. copy and delete
    If sdfrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    sdfrg.Copy dfCell
    sdfrg.Delete xlShiftUp
    
ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```